# How to get the triggers associated with a lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

So I have a lambda function and I'm trying to send a request through the aws sdk to retrieve a list of the triggers associated with that lambda function. I've seen another post related to this one that says to use a workaround by using the getPolicy request, however the getPolicy request returns a "The resource you requested does not exist" every other request that I've sent to that lambda works just fine. I'm assuming that lambda just doesn't have a policy attached to it. So now I'm incapable of using that workaround to grab the triggers associated with that lambda. Any advice?

Comment: XY problem? why do you need them?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this problem, I am facing the same issue as well.